# Can I use ARIMA with hour data for two year prediction?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, statsmodels

I am trying to use ARIMA model for time series forecasting. My data consists of hour by hour energy consumption. I have data for one year. So I have total 24*365 observations for energy consumption. Moreover, I have hourly weather data(24*365 obs) during this period. My goal is to forecast two year energy consumption hour by hour. So I have to forecast 24*365*2 energy consumption for next two year. And I also have weather data(24*365*2) for next two year. Can I use ARIMA in this problem?

My problem is to forecast energy consumption for two years with weather data and previous energy consumption data. To summarize, I have 2016 energy consumption data. And I have 2016, 2017, 2018 weather data. I have to forecast 2017 and 2018 energy consumption hour by hour.

If I can use ARIMA model in this forecasting problem,

1. How can I select p,d,q parameters? Can I consider 24*7 = 168 for p? I think the seasonality exists weekly basis.
2. How can I incorporate my weather data into my ARIMA model? I googled it and found there are exogenous options in ARIMA function. And I got coefficients for weather data from model summary. I don't know how to proceed. I have observations for next two year weather. But I have to use predicted value for lagged energy consumption terms in ARIMA. How can I combine these observed values and predicted values for my model?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please ask your questions as separate posts. You can make as many as you want.

Comment: How do you have hourly weather predictions for the two next years? Who are making them? Can you trust them?

Comment: From an operational point of view, you might want to read and then try using `prophet` which makes your life easier in terms of incorporating extra regressors among other things. https://facebook.github.io/prophet/ I'm curious, too, as @kjetilbhalvorsen, what is the source of your hourly weather forecasts - it's pretty high resolution with a long forecast horizon

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm sorry to cause confusion. My problem is to forecast energy consumption for two years with weather data and previous energy consumption data. To summarize, I have 2016 energy consumption data. And I have 2016, 2017, 2018 weather data. I have to forecast 2017 and 2018 energy consumption.

Comment: Please include this information, and more, in the original post (OP) as an edit.